# What is the difference between 'Build directory' and 'Working directory' in Qt?

Tags: qt

In Qt creator, and in the 'Projects' tab; under 'Build' there is the 'Build directory'.

And under 'Run', there is the 'working directory'.

What is the difference between these two directories? Are not they supposed to be the same? Since the project is going to be built in one directory, the produced executable is going to be in that directory, but not another one, isn't it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The build directory is where Qt will build your project.

The working / current directory is the directory the application is currently working in. This can be set in a number of ways, on shortcut level, when you start a process, when you execute an application from another directory command prompt, or internally via the static `QDir::setCurrent()` function.

Not to be confused with the application directory, which is where the application executable resides.